# How to check for vowels using a helper method and return a string in Java?

Tags: java, methods, return

I am attempting to use a helper method that checks if all characters in a word are vowels.

I am then attempting to create another method that uses a Scanner as a parameter and will continuously ask the user to enter a word until the user enters a word that contains all vowels. (The word doesn't have to be a word, it could be ieuo).

I cannot figure out how to have the method verify the scanner is all vowels and then return the correct output.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class LabFinish {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter a word: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        askForWords(scan);

    public static boolean isAllVowels(Scanner scan) {
        String str = scan.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i <= str.length(); i++)
            if ((str.charAt(i) == 'a') ||
                    (str.charAt(i) == 'e') ||
                    (str.charAt(i) == 'i') ||
                    (str.charAt(i) == 'o') ||
                    (str.charAt(i) == 'u')) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
    }

    public static String askForWords(Scanner scan) {
        if (isAllVowels(scan) == true) {
            return "Finally all vowels, we are done.";
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Enter a word: ");
            Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            if (isAllVowels(scan1) == true) {
                return "Finally all vowels, we are done.";
            }
            else {
                return "Enter a word";
            }

        }
    }
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not use a regex expression?

Comment: Because then they'd have two problems?

Comment: Not an answer, but a recommendation - always use `{ }` characters with a `for` loop.  In your example, it's not obvious whether the `return false;` is inside the `for` loop or outside.  It's actually outside, but your indentation makes it look like it's inside.  And the difference is important.  So always use `{ }`, just to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things that should help you forward:

Merely *returning* a String from a method doesn't *output* it anywhere. So, replacing

```
askForWords(scan);
```

with

```
System.out.println(askForWords(scan));
```

in `main()` will show you the result of the method.

While you're checking for vowels, you need to iterate through the *whole word*, instead of stopping at the first vowel you encounter. Using your current code, the easiest fix is to invert the values of the `return` statements and the truth value of the comparison:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    if ( !( // <- if the string has any other characters than the ones below, return a falsey
          (str.charAt(i) == 'a') 
            || (str.charAt(i) == 'e') 
            || (str.charAt(i) == 'i') 
            || (str.charAt(i) == 'o')
            || (str.charAt(i) == 'u'))) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

You also have some other issues, such as the code only running for a maximum of two input strings (you'd need a loop instead of a single `if-else`), but these are a bit off-topic for this question.